# AJAX call - 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call a function on the server side through AJAX. The function inside connect_v2.ascx file which is contained inside user/module. Here's my code for the call :

```
    function Request() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/user/modules/connect_v2.ascx/Follow") %>',
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
}
```

My server side function is as follows :

```
    [WebMethod]
public static void Follow()
{


}
```

I get 404 Not Found error which means I'm not providing a correct url. Can anyone please help me see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: check path may be it is not correct.do console.log of url and see.

Comment: I checked the path. I see nothing wrong with it. the path to the file is "/user/modules/connect_v2.ascx"

Comment: Check the path that is genereated by `ResolveUrl`

Comment: @AhmedMujtaba is this MVC or Webforms?

Comment: I think we cannot call a method directly in a user control using Jquery Ajax

Comment: @SankarRaj It's a Webforms application

Comment: @PrashantMehta I've used the same mathod to call a function inside a .aspx file and it seems to be working fine

Comment: @WaqarAhmed the url a get is "/user/modules/connect_v2.ascx/Follow"

Comment: why are you trying to use a usercontrol like a webservice?

Comment: You should [Try this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339162/Android-push-notification-implementation-using-ASP)

Comment: @singsuyash yeah maybe I'll write this function in a .aspx file and call it there

Comment: `.ascx` extensions are usercontrols. Are you looking for `.asmx` files? When you choose your template by `Add New Item` , you can see the file's template name.

Comment: Oh so you can't access web methods inside user controls? hmm I didn't know that

Comment: @singsuyash I have created a web service file and added my function there but I'm now getting "500 Internal server" error. can you help me out with this?

Comment: Learn how to use a tool called fiddler. It will give you more insight on what is going on with a http request response.

Comment: @singsuyash I have used fiddler for MVC Web API . Does it work the same for webforms?

Comment: It works with any framework that uses http request/response

Comment: @singsuyash okay cool. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have `WebMethod` inside `ascx`. Better solution would be create `asmx` and write `WebMethod` there.

Comment: calling the function inside the webservice file is giving me '500 Internal Server Error'. Can you help me out with that

Comment: check google chrome console for errors. and reply me

Answer (score 2):

try beginning the path with "../" instead of "~/"